# javascript loops discrepancies for beginners

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I wonder why seemingly equal loops lead to the different results.

First loop

```
 for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    }
```

Results:

```
  0
  1
  2
  3
  4
```

The result is fully understandable and expectable behaviour.

However, the following loop

```
var i=0;
while ( i<5) {
    console.log(i);
    i++;
}
```

leads to the different results, such that

```
0
1
2
3
4
4
```

As a beginner in programming I don't really understand why it is so, what the source of discrepancy in this case.

Comment: That's not right... Are you sure you haven't added another `console.log(i)` somewhere?

Comment: Are you testing these code snippets by entering them in your browser's console?

Answer (score 3):

If you change to

```
var i=0;
while ( i<5) {
    console.log("i is " + i);
    i++;
}
```

then you will see in the console that it does output the correct values "i is 0", 1,2,3,4. The console also outputs the value of the last evaluated statement, which is why you see an additional 4.

If I run the `for` example in Google Chrome it prints an additional `undefined` because it outputs the value of the last evaluated statement, which is the console.log.

Comment: but why not in-case  of for

Comment: this in important line you need to add in your answer that in for loop `i` goes out-of-scope as loop terminates that the reason last values differs, &+

Comment: But `i` doesn't go out of scope after the `for` loop. If you add an extra `console.log(i)` after the `for` loop it prints `5` and then `undefined`.

Comment: @nnnnnn Thanks also, I corrected my answer. As you say, it is nothing to do with scope.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are seeing is an extra value printed by the interactive Javascript console that is the "result" of this code snippet.

Answer (score 2):

The Javascript console prints the result of the `for()` and `while()` expression . If you run the first loop console  :

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   console.log(i);
}
```

The results will be :

```
0
1
2
3
4
undefined
```

Here it prints the value of `var i` which is local to the scope of the `for()` loop , hence `undefined` outside it.

In the second case , just the `var i` is defined outside the loop body , hence it prints the latest value of `i` which is not `undefined`.

Comment: but why `undefined` in for?

Comment: Why is the result of the `while()` 4? Also, `i` is not local to the `for()` loop given that JavaScript doesn't have block scope (if you add a `console.log(i)` after the `for` loop it'll print `5` and then `undefined`).

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Because `console.log()` is the last expression `eval()`'d and returns `undefined`. Whereas `i++` is the last in `while`, resulting in `4`.

Comment: Ahaa New Idiot Got it!! Thanks :) your last edit was important that in  for `var i` goes out of scope ---highlight this in your answer I think. (the difference is in for `i` goes out-of-scope as for-loop terminates)

Comment: In the for loop `console.log()` isn't the last _expression_ evaluated, `i < 5` is.

Comment: @nnnnnn Please explain the output , I am a noob in Javascript , just wrote what I thought could be the reason !

Comment: Thanks for the extra details @JonathanLonowski - I was just objecting to the use of "last _expression_", and trying to prompt the other poster to provide more detail...

Comment: @nnnnnn Well, I believe that was me. :) And, yeah, it was a poor description. Should have been: "*the last statement evaluated that determines the loop's own return value*."

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems the snippets are being evaluated, as through `eval()` or a REPL/Console, the extra `4` is the loop's return value.

And, yes, loops have [return values](http://es5.github.io/#x12.6.2).

> 1. Return (normal, *V*, empty).

Though, it's not something that's particularly useful to you in most cases, as attempting to retrieve it normally gives you a lovely `SyntaxError`. :)

```
var a = for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) i;
console.log(a);
```

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token for
```

However, `eval()` the loop, and you can see it.

```
var a = eval('for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) i;');
console.log(a);
```

```
4
```

The value returned, *V*, comes from the evaluation of the loop's *Statement*. In the above case, that's simply `i;`, which is `4` the last time.

For your snippets, the `for` loop's result is `undefined` from `console.log(i);` and the `while` loop's result is `4` from `i++;`